# PhpMyAdmin session is closed after 1440 seconds

Tags: phpmyadmin, session

Adding this to config file is supposed to avoid it

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LoginCookieValidity'] = 2592000;
```

Now checking cookies I can see the one named pmaUser-1 expires on March 21, that's correct.
However sessions keep expiring after 1440 seconds.
I know it's not PHP, I have many other sites running in the same server and their sessions last forever.
Any idea what's going on?

Comment: did you restart Apache?

Comment: @steve why would this be apacje related? It looks like php code so Apache wouldnt care?

Comment: @davidgo I am not sure it is, but since what the OP is doing hasn't worked, anything is worth a try.

Comment: I'm not even using Apache, and this has nothing to do with the web server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509995/how-to-manually-set-phpmyadmin-login-cookie-validity-time#30935349 has some advice on this - including other places this value is being set which may override your config file.